# Get Unique values during Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am looping through an array and getting the data that I need.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {

    var merchName = finalArray[i].merchName;
    var amName = finalArray[i].amName;
    var amEmail = finalArray[i].amEmail;
    var txnID = finalArray[i].transID;
    var transAccount = finalArray[i].transAccount;
}
```

What I am trying to do at this point is only show unique data in the loop.

For example var transAccount could be in the array 5 times. I only one to display that in my table once. How can I go about accomplishing this ?

Final Array is constructed like so; just as an object:

```
   finalArray.push({
            transID: tmpTrans,
            transAccount: tmpAccount,
            amEmail: amEmail,
            merchName: merchName,
            amPhone: amPhone,
            amName: amName

        });
```

Comment: Can you show, how `finalArray` is constructed?

Comment: `   finalArray.push({
                transID: tmpTrans,
                transAccount: tmpAccount,
                amEmail: amEmail,
                merchName: merchName,
                amPhone: amPhone,
                amName: amName

            });`

Comment: if `transAccount` appears in the array 5 times, which value do you want the programme to display in the table? The first occurrence? The last?

Comment: I intend to have duplicates in the array. At this point in my code and am saying "Here is the account number, show me all the details tied to that account". If that account number exits, we don't print it in the table as its part of the first instance of it. The first instance of it is fine.

Comment: @CarlHussey Hmm... I think it's better to take care of this when creating `finalArray`, even the name of it tells it should be ready for use...

Comment: It's not that it's not ready , it contains everything I need.

Step 1, I do an XML call and gather data from an internal website and present it to the user along with checkboxes before each row.

Step 2, user selects all of the transactions that they want to escalate to the manager.

Comment: Step 3, it maps the transaction of from step 2 with the array in step 1 to get the account number.

Step 4, using the account number, XML call to each of the accounts selected and find the managers email address. If in step 2 the user selected multiple transactions that has the same account manager, that is where the question falls...

Comment: In step 5, I present all of the account managers with a button they can click to see the transactions tied to it. If American Airlines has 3 payments being sent to the account manager, I only want to show American Airlines once because I will show all 3 transactions when they click the button.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

```
var merhcData = {};
var amName = {};
// and so on

for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
    merchData[finalArray[i].merchName] = finalArray[i].merchName;
    amName[finalArray[i].amName] = finalArray[i].amName;
    // and so on
}
```

If you are sure, that data in merchName will never be equal amName or other field - you can use one data object instead of several (merchData, amName...)

Comment: Could you explain this a little? I am creating a table using all of the data in the for loop but want to have unique merchNames.

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is simple associated array, imitation of 'set' data structure in javascript (example: http://www.javascriptexamples.org/2011/01/17/how-to-implement-a-set-in-javascript/). If you want to have unique merchNames - simply add index: data['merchName'+i]

Comment: @CarlHussey In that case you've included irrelevant code into your question. The relevant one would be the code and data which populates objects in `finalArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var allTransAccount = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {

     var merchName = finalArray[i].merchName;
     var amName = finalArray[i].amName;
     var amEmail = finalArray[i].amEmail;
     var txnID = finalArray[i].transID;

     var transAccount = finalArray[i].transAccount;
     if(allTransAccount[finalArray[i].transAccount]) {
        var transAccount = '';
     }
     else {
        allTransAccount[transAccount] = true;
     }
  }
```

Comment: In side this loop I am creating tables rows for each record and appending them to my table. So I need to say if Merchant name doesnt exist, { //append code here } else { //this would include nothing so it just skipped adding the row }

Comment: @CarlHussey then in the else block after `allTransAccount[transAccount] = true;` you will add the row.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is likely a [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29). (see [zakas for ES6 implementation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/09/25/ecmascript-6-collections-part-1-sets/). To emulate this using javascript, you could use an object with the key as one of your properties (account would be a good bet, as aperl said) which you test before using your raw array.

```
var theSet={};

for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
 var transAccount = finalArray[i].transAccount;
 var merchName = finalArray[i].merchName;
 var amName = finalArray[i].amName;
 var amEmail = finalArray[i].amEmail;
 var txnID = finalArray[i].transID;

 if(!theSet[transAccount]){
    //add to your table
    theSet[transAccount]===true;
}
```

This will prevent entries of duplicate data.